# How to trace mysql log in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, logging, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-sql

I just setup the phpMyAdmin for the Google Cloud SQL (http://goo.gl/Ey53WS) but am unable to finish at step "Log in to phpMyAdmin". I can just see the error message "Cannot log in to the MySQL server" from the login page.

Is there anyway for me to trace the error log from the MySQL (or the possible error for this)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can enable Mysql flags `general_log` ON and `log_output` TABLE.

Then you can run query in table 'mysql': `select * from general_log;` and see if there are failed connections.

You can look at the App Engine logs too.

Check login (root by default) and password (empty by default) in PHP config file and check that CloudSQL authorize access to your application.

Comment: Here is more info on how to set those flags: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-flags